# Decode X509Certificate2's Serial Number?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

With the sample "Self Signed Certificate" in X509Certificate format, I'm looking at the Certificate's Serial Number.

I couldn't figure out what 'encoding type' or 'converstion type' is being used, or how it's being used.  The Serial Number is

`4f:4b:6c:4c:f9:56:44:eb:85:0a:b1:36:b6:ec:e0:12` in Certificate Raw Output

or

`4F4B6C4CF95644EB850AB136B6ECE012` in C# X509Certificate2 Raw Output

Either of those 2 values, when converted to Serial Number's plain text is

`105400630530142072027530130683799068690`

I assumed I only need to convert the Hexadecimal value to ASCII text but it gave me this.

`OKlL?VD??\n?6???\u0012`

So that is not it.  What decoding method is involved to produce the correct Serial Number here?

[Edited] - Just learned it is "ASN.1 binary integer up to 20 octets" now.

Answer (score 3):

`4F4B6C4CF95644EB850AB136B6ECE012` is the big-endian hexadecimal representation of the serial number (aka it's just `0x4F4B6C4CF95644EB850AB136B6ECE012`).

Using something like http://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php to convert that hexadecimal number to a decimal number we get `105400630530142072027530130683799068690`.

Be aware that in .NET `GetSerialNumber()` returns it little-endian, but the `SerialNumber` property returns it big-endian.